# Why is fread reading absurd numbers?

Tags: c, binary, fread

I wish to read a file containing 5 numbers on each line and put a every number into an array, for example:

*FILE: 1 2 3 4 5   |  ARRAYS: a[1] = 1, a[1] = 2, a[2] = 3, etc.*

However, when I try exactly this file with the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char nomeDoArquivo[100];
    int iter, teste[5];

    fgets(nomeDoArquivo, 100, stdin);
    nomeDoArquivo[strlen(nomeDoArquivo) - 1] = '\0';

    FILE *f = fopen (nomeDoArquivo, "rb");
    if (f == NULL) 
        exit (1);

    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        int buffer [5];
        fread(&buffer[a], sizeof(int), 1, f);
        teste[a] = buffer[a];
        
        printf("%d: %d\n", a, teste[a]);
    }

    fclose (f);
    return 0;
}
```

It returns this:

```
0: 171051569
1: 171182643
2: 53
3: 0
4: 0
```

I've tried everything. What on earth is going on? I appreciate any help.

Comment: `fread` doesn't magically know that, because you opened the file in binary-mode (which isn't even a thing as far as `fread` is concerned), that your attempt to read into the memory backdrop of a platform-dependent `int`, should somehow translate text transparently. That isn't how `fread` works. [See `fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread), where you'll notice the *type* of the data target is irrelevant; all it cares about is how many octets you tell it to read, where you tell it to store them, and whether they're available or not.

Answer (score 2):

The file is in the wrong format. It contains text, not binary, numbers. You can tell because `171051569` is the little endian encoding of `"\x31\x0a\x32\x0a"`, or `"1\n2\n"` after converting the ASCII hex codes to characters.

If you want to open the file as `"rb"` and read it with `fread` then you need to save the numbers in binary format.

Alternatively, if you want to read it as is then open it as `"r"` and use text input routines such as `fgets` and `sscanf`.